# Is there any difference in quality between SDF and TTF fonts if the font is never zoomed / rotated?

Tags: opengl, text, fonts

I am trying to understand Signed Distance Field font rendering and from what I understand they are used to preserve quality when zooming, rotating rendered fonts. Is there any difference in the quality of a TTF font (rendered onto a texture) vs a font rendered via SDF if the font is never zoomed or rotated? For example, in a 2D game would there be any improvement in rendering via SDF vs a TTF font rendered onto a texture (other than reduced memory usage)?

Comment: I would imagine a high DPI screen would be an edge case, but having a conditional change from the high and normal DPI versions of the font would suffice. It depends on what you are optimizing for if you want speed vs memory or vice-versa, but unless you are rendering a lot of text I would not bother.

Comment: By “never zoomed or rotated” do you mean things always viewed straight-on from a fixed distance, e.g. things in on-screen UI rather than textured on 3D objects? For such an application there's nothing wrong with rendering on the CPU and uploading to a texture.

Comment: One issue would be the fact that typesetting using an OpenType (not "TTF", that's just one of the four common Opentype flavours) font is not done letter by letter. So if you want to render actual proper text, SDF is effectively not an option. If all you want to do is "render letters one after another" (which is certainly not the same as rendering text) then SDF is fine.